Securing sudoers entry with sha512 checksum
If I have a custom script and I want to run it as sudo but without being prompted for the password, I normally do an entry in my sudoers file like the one below:
username ALL = NOPASSWD: sha512:d5655d0f3f1772046a2ff996942d2f1e5s3f9e9fcb93dc062463ec9584sd67cbcecf459215ac627s5eff2036df47a7c6f036e6f75e53c83362dc42024s95b795 /home/username/script.sh

The sha512 checksum protects the script from being manipulated to take advantage of it running as a root without a password.
I do however have some entries that require specific script to be executed by a specific binary, such as this:
Debian-snmp ALL = NOPASSWD: /bin/sh /etc/snmp/raspberry.sh

What is the correct syntax to include sha512 checksum for raspberry.sh script here? The user Debian-snmp doesn't have a shell so I need to specify it in this line to make raspberry.sh execute, but I can't figure out the correct syntax for sha512.

This feels like an XY problem but I'm not sure.  Seems like the correct question should be "how to I make a script execute without specifying sh to run it"

"The user Debian-snmp doesn't have a shell"... but that doesn't mean they have to use /bin/sh to execute scripts which are otherwise executable

The user shell has nothing to do with the interpreter a shell script needs to run... and has little to do with what sudo does.  If you need sh to run the script, the script isn't set up properly to run stand alone.  So changing sudo is X, the Y problem is fixing the script.

@user10489 well the script was provided by someone else and I haven't thought about it that way but I think you are right, I will try to modify it myself and get it updated so that it can run without /bin/sh.

... @ProTofik it should just be a matter of modifying the script's ownership / mode so that user Debian-snmp has execute permission (either as owner or via group membership) - you shouldn't need to modify the script itself unless it lacks an appropriate shebang

You might have to set the first line of the script to #!/bin/sh or similar if that isn't already there in addition to setting permissions.
